How to understand ${\pi \over (A^2+B^2)^{3 /2}}\int_{a}^{b}[Ax + Bf(x) + C]^2|Af'(x)-B|dx$
I'm told that
$$
V={\pi \over (A^2+B^2)^{3 /2}}\int_{a}^{b}[Ax + Bf(x) + C]^2|Af'(x)-B|dx
$$
is the volume of the solid of revolution of the curve
$$
L:y=f(x), a \le x \le b
$$
around the line
$$
L_0:Ax+By+C=0
$$
if

$f(x)$ is differentiable.
Any line perpendicular to $L_0$ intersects $L$ at most once.

I think if you compute the distance from the curve to the line
$$
d = {\left|Ax+Bf(x)+C\right| \over \sqrt{A^2+B^2}}
$$
shound't the volume simply be
$$
V = \pi \int_{a}^{b}d^2dx
$$
Comparing the two equation for $V$, I don't get it what is this part for
$$
\left|Af'(x)-B\right| \over \sqrt{A^2+B^2}
$$

What is $d$ in terms of $f$, $A$, $B$, $C$?

$d$ is the distance from a point $(x, f(x))$ to $L_0$, the definition has been added.

If
$$L_0:Ax+By+C=0, \tag{0}$$
the straight line with equation
$$L_1:-Bx+Ay+C=0 \tag{1}$$
is orthogonal to $L_0$ (their normal vectors $\binom{B}{-A}$ and $\binom{A}{B}$ are orthogonal).
Therefore, the signed distance to line $L_1$ is
$$\delta_1:=\frac{-Bx+Ay+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\tag{2}$$
Please note that $\delta_1$ measures in particular the signed distance as we travel along line $L_0$.
Using (2), we have the following formula for the volume :
$$V={\pi \over (A^2+B^2)}\int_{a}^{b}[Ax + Bf(x) + C]^2 \color{red}{d\delta_1}\tag{3}$$
Differentiating (2), we get :
$$d\delta_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}(-B dx +A dy) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} dx(-B+A\frac{dy}{dx})=dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} (-B+A f'(x))\tag{4}$$
(The unsigned distance being taken by (4) with absolute value signs).
Plugging (4) into (3) gives your formula.

Any comment ?...
